# Subquery in Linq as a List union

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Imagine you have `Voyage` class that it has `Tally` class in. This `Tally` class has collection of `Shipment` class. I am trying to get a list of all Tallies class as a union Shipment List.
I've coded this:

```
var shipments = booking.Voyages.Select(q => q.Tallies.Select(t => t.Loadings.Select(l=>l.Shipment))).ToList();
```

But the problem is that it returns result as a `List<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Shipment>>>` while I'm expecting a result in form of `IEnumerable<Shipment>`.
Is there any solution for this problem or I have to get their Shipments with `for` loop.

Comment: if you wish to convert list to array, use .ToArray()

Comment: @Arphile - No I need to have a result as a List<>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `SelectMany` function.  `SelectMany` will flatten a nested `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>;` to just an `IEnumerable<T>` of all the children.  Because you are multiple levels deep you will need multiple `SelectMany`s.

```
var shipments = booking.Voyages.SelectMany(
                  q => q.Tallies.SelectMany( 
                      t => t.Loadings.SelectMany(l=>l.Shipment)
                   )
                 ).ToList();
```

If the `Shipment` property is a single object navigation property rather than a collection you will want the following code instead.

```
var shipments = booking.Voyages.SelectMany(
                  q => q.Tallies.SelectMany( 
                      t => t.Loadings.Select(l=>l.Shipment)
                   )
                 ).ToList();
```

Comment: Shipment is class. I mean the sum is that collect Shipment entities as a collection and return as a list.

Comment: It return error ('Headway.Domain.Models.Shipment' to 'long)

Comment: Answer edited. You want nested selectmany. Alternatively you can go the other way and select from the shipments table where the parent loading.booking matches

Comment: Imagine you have Voyage class that it has Tally class in. This Tally class has collection of Shipment class. I am trying to get a list of all Shipment class in Loading class as a list of shipments

Comment: I saw edited answer but it return this error (Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[Headway.Domain.Models.Voyage,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Headway.Domain.Models.Shipment]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Headway.Domain.Models.Shipment]'.)

Comment: @SasanK your ToList() is in the wrong place, check your bracket positions. You have put the ToList after the inner SelectMany not the closing bracket of the Outer